# Create a new lookup table where data already exists

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2013

I am working on a database in MS Access 2013 which has a considerable amount of non-normalised data, and I want to move them out to alternate tables and use them as lookups in the main table. However, when I create a lookup column, MS Access deletes the data and there is far too much data to reset every record by hand.

Is there a way in Access 2013 to create such a lookup without losing the data?

Please don't comment about how using lookup tables in Access is bad. I have read posts like the one below and I disagree with most of the points there, and some of them are just simply wrong.

http://access.mvps.org/access/lookupfields.htm

Below is a sample of my data. I need to extract the 2nd and 3rd fields to other tables. If I can do this with them, I can do it with the others.

[image]

Presently this is stored as text in the fields. I would like to remove them and replace them with FK id's.

Comment: Do you really need a lookup column?  How do you plan on using it?  A lot of times it is more efficient to write the query yourself.

Comment: Its not really about the lookup features. Its about the normalisation process. There is too much repeated data that can be separated out to other tables and related back. If I can do this, I would be happy. The ability to lookup is a bonus I dont need.

Comment: Can you provide an example section of the table that needs to be normalized?

Comment: Updated to include a sample image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could create your second table and add the data to the table.  Then update the first table to match the records to each other

Let say you have the following table:

```
CustOrders
ID       Customer     DateOrdered
123      K-Mart       01/01/2013
124      K Mart       01/05/2013
125      Walmart      02/05/2013
126      Walmart      03/07/2013
127      Miejers      03/11/2013
128      K-Mart       03/12/2013
```

You could find out all of the `Customers` that are in the `CustOrders` table by performing the following:

```
SELECT DISTINCT Customer From CustOrders
```

Then create a record in the following table for each:

```
Customers
ID       Customer
1        K-Mart
2        Walmart
3        Miejers
```

Then you could Update the `CustOrders` table by performing the following:

```
UPDATE CustOrders SET Customer = 1 WHERE Customer = 'K-Mart' OR Customer = 'K Mart'
```

Of course you would have to do this for each distinct customer you have.

Then if you want you could change the data type of the `Customer` field in the `CustOrders` table to `Long Integer`.

Lastly I would create a combo box on any entry/edit form that has the following `RowSource`:

```
SELECT ID, Customer FROM Customers ORDER BY Customer
```

Set the combo box to limit from list and bind to column 1.

Comment: I already had most of my answer typed before you posted your update to your question.  If you need further clarification let me know.

Comment: Im going to give it a shot. Thanks and if it works I will accept it as the answer. Thanks again.

Comment: Your welcome, FYI, I always recommend against using Access Lookup fields when possible.  It is easy enough to perform on your own.

Comment: This is a good answer and thank you, however there is a problem. I do know databases fairly well. Normally I work with SQL Server, its been a while since I worked with access. The problem is actually the ability to do this efficiently. I could have done the above query and steps too quite easily (and did), the issue is that I have about 40 different fields in the 2nd col, and over 100 in the 3rd. Its not feasible to write individual update queries on all of them. Is there a way to do some sort of cross checking that would create the tables, look for matches, and do the updates as needed.

Comment: Yes, but if the fields are text fields that allowed the user to put whatever they wanted in them, you may end up with garbage in the new table.  Like in my example K-Mart is misspelled in one of the records.

Comment: On the user side, they see a drop down box so their choices are limited. As a result, the data entered, while stored as text, is always identical. If there were some problem data, it would be very rare and I could handle it on a record by record basis. Presently I have some 5000 records to run through, Im pretty sure there would be mistakes in less than 1% of those. Thats much easier to handle manually!

Comment: `INSERT INTO Customers (Customer) SELECT DISTINCT Customer FROM CustOrders` would be an example related to my answer.

Comment: I was trying different variations of this but was not having much success. I figured out a way to get me there though and I did it because of your help. Thanks again for your time.

Comment: How about: `INSERT INTO Customers SELECT DISTINCT CustOrders.Customer FROM CustOrders`.  This is assuming that `ID` is set as an autonumbered field.

Comment: I made a make table query using your select distinct command. Then I went into the table and set its properties (PK). Since only one field exists (I didn't create a numbered ID field), I was able to go back to the main table, use the lookup wizard, and relate the tables exactly. It worked. So I repeated the process and got no errors so far. At this rate I'll be done before bed time. :)